# How do I pass a map to a web service via SOAP in Python?

Tags: php, python, soap

I'm trying to develop a web service, and I'm using the Yii PHP framework, which can [generate WSDL](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.webservice).  I've got a working PHP client, that uses code of the form:

```
<?php

$wsdlURL='someUrl';
$client = new SoapClient($wsdlURL);
$inputArray = array('a'=>'1', 'b'=>'2');

// make the actual soap call
$client->someMethod($inputArray);
```

That generates a request of the form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:SystemsControllerwsdl" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:someMethod>
      <inputArray xsi:type="ns2:Map">
        <item>
          <key xsi:type="xsd:string">a</key>
          <value xsi:type="xsd:string">1</value>
        </item>
        <item>
          <key xsi:type="xsd:string">b</key>
          <value xsi:type="xsd:string">2</value>
        </item>
      </inputArrayArray>
    </ns1:someMethod>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I'm trying to do the same with python now, and am using [SOAPpy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/SOAPpy/).  This isn't a hard requirement, it's just the SOAP library that seems to work.  (I wasn't able to get [suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/) to parse my WSDL.)

In any case, I've got this python:

```
import SOAPpy


wsdlURL = 'someURL'
client = SOAPpy.WSDL.Proxy(wsdlURL)
args = {'a':'1', 'b':'2'}

soap_map = []
for key in args:
    inner = {"key":key,"value":args[key]}
    soap_map.append(inner)

wsdl.someMethod(soap_map)
```

The request is close, but instead is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:someMethod xmlns:ns1="urn:SystemsControllerwsdl" SOAP-ENC:root="1">
      <v1 xmlns:ns2="http://soapinterop.org/xsd" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns2:SOAPStruct[6]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
        <item>
          <value xsi:type="xsd:string">1</value>
          <key xsi:type="xsd:string">a</key>
        </item>
        <item>
          <value xsi:type="xsd:string">2</value>
          <key xsi:type="xsd:string">b</key>
        </item>
      </v1>
    </ns1:someMethod>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I'm guessing that due to the different namespace that this request is generated in, my web service doesn't know how to handle the input.  I'm guessing if I could just change the type into the right namespace while submitting via python, I'd be good to go, but I couldn't figure out how to do this using SOAPpy.